# How to make everything run as root in ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, privileges, su

I have setup a virtual machine for compiling software for linux which I develop on Windows.

I setup to automount a windows folder, run compilation scripts and then just shutdown. The machine isn't even connected to a network.

I have read a few question to answer it myself but the only thing I can make happen is that I do not have to type in a password and auto login my user in ubuntu.

But what I want to do is: I want to execute a command in the terminal. I want it to execute with root privilidges, every command and always under any circumstances. I do not want to type "sudo" or "su" every time I go to the console to compile my programs (some scripts require root privilidges, some not, you don't know until you run it and a bunch of errors appear which makes it really frustrating).

So how do I do this?

Optional: How can I make everything in the default Ubuntu GUI also run as admin? Eg gedit when double clicking on a file?

*Proclaimer*
I looked for [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97278/how-can-i-make-everything-just-assume-im-running-as-the-superuser) [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt) about this topic but they do not answer the question. Every answer denies an correct answer on a "it's not secure" basis (even though users state most of the times they are aware of the security risks)... and I do not care about a non-networked OS's security. It's just a matter of loading a previous snapshot of the compilation VM if anything breaks.

Comment: Enable root login using the above link question, and sign into the GUI using username `root` and the password you set for it.

Comment: I do have to log in AS root? Can't do this for my own account? Well okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First enable the root account by setting a password:

```
sudo passwd
```

Then enable manual login in LightDM (assuming 14.04):

```
sudo tee /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-allow-manual.conf <<EOF
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login=true
EOF
```

Restart LightDM:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Login as root. You'll have to type both username and password. To enable autologin for root:

```
sudo tee /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/51-auto-root.conf <<EOF
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=root
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
EOF
service lightdm restart
```

Comment: ah finally, I wanted it to login automatically so I edited `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to login root automatically, nice, thanks again! :)